# setTimeout("this.disabled=false",3000); is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prevent duplicated data to database when the user click the submit button multiple times within a very short time (eg double click speed). First I disable the button after one click, then enable the button again after 3 seconds. I don't know why setTimeout("this.disabled=false",3000); is not working on jquery. Please help me out, below is my codes :

```
$(function() { 
    $(".btnSendResp").click(function() {
        this.disabled = true;
        setTimeout("this.disabled=false",3000);
        postinResp();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have the wrong `this`.

You need to save a reference to `this` in a local variable, then **pass a function** to `setTimeout` that uses the variable.

For example:

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() { 
    self.disabled = false;
}, 3000);
```

Comment: @Slaks, actually I don't understand why do we need to pass the function() into setTimeout since the setTimeout is already wrapped inside $(function(). Moreover I don't understand after we pass function() into setTimeout, why can't we use (this) without set it to a variable?

Comment: @zac: You can't use this inside the setTimeout because the context has changed. Inside the setTimeout function `this` no longer refers to the button that is clicked. The function is passed in because that is what setTimeout is expecting. It isn't expecting an assignment operation.

Comment: @Rob Sutherland, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { 
    $(".btnSendResp").click(function() {
        var that = this;
        that.disabled = true;
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.disabled=false;
        },3000);
        postinResp();
    });
});
```